# Vertical css navigation link titles cause loss of focus

Tags: css, title, html-lists, mousehover

An older version of my site used a vertical navigation bar.
I was unable to add 'title' attributes as these would result in loss of focus on a sub menu when the pointer was on the title popup.

Anyone have any experience with dealing with this and code that can be used to resolve this issue for future reference purpose?

Kindly refer me to any guides that you may feel of assistance.

Comment: Personally I'd avoid having title attributes on links unless they provide additional information missing from the link text. The habit of replicating link text in the title attribute is bad for accessibility (screen readers will read the text twice to the user) and is unlikely to aid SEO.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja: Who said the titles were replicated from the link text? @ thejartender: I'd love to see a demo of this, I've never seen the problem you speak of and I use titles all the time. Does this *really* happen? You're sure it's not caused by something else?

Comment: @drmonkeyninja The titles are not duplicates of the element text. An example would be a url in the title and internationalized text for element text.

Comment: @Wesley Murch sure please visit thejarbar.org left vertical navigation bar is the culprit. Seems to also be performance related (less likely to loose focus in css3 compliant browsers).

Comment: @thejartender: I tried FF7 and IE8 on our site and did *not* see the issue you speak of (and didn't expect to). Can you confirm your browser and OS?

Comment: @ Wesley Murch I am using all those browsers. FF 7 is using a mored modern stylesheet and is not an issue. When using IE8 (not in quirks mode), I lose focus on third level ul classes. It appears to happen only when the mouse reaches the same area as the title. As it's been confirmed that titles have no SEO use, I am removing them from the left navigation bar.

Comment: Title attributes may or may not have SEO benefits (not sure what you mean by "it's been confirmed"), but it's irrelevant because they have other benefits (to the user). I think bailing out was a poor choice and there are ways to correct the quirks you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to remove the title attribute in the ul. It's no so important from a SEO point of view.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I asked this and for anyone stumbling on this, I had to remove titles on my horizontal nav column. This should not be an issue though when using self explanatory names.

This problem can also be fixed by adjusting CSS hights, widths and positioning of related elements.